# How can we add a SPFx webpart to an application page in SharePoint 2019?

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-designer, spfx, spfx-webparts, application-pages

We are trying to add a SPFx webpart to an application page but are encountering some issues. The steps we have taken are the following:

1. We create a new web part page in SharePoint designer and add the webpart through the UI.
2. We open the page in advanced edit mode in SharePoint designer and copy the markup for the webpart WebPartPages:ClientSideWebPart which references our SPFx webpart.
3. We paste this webpart into a .aspx application page in our solution in Visual Studio (inside a webpart zone with the ID the webpart references).
4. When we save and deploy the solution we can see the title of the webpart, but not the content. We get an error in the console saying:
   "AdminPage.aspx:539 Cannot load the web part wrapper on this page. Use the browser Back button to retry. If the problem persists, contact the administrator of the site."

We found out that cause of this issue is that the script "/_layouts/15/next/spclient/nb-no/sp-classic-page-assembly.js" and an inline javascript where the variable spClientSidePageContext and the startSpfx function is defined is not loaded on the page.
By adding these manually to the .aspx application page we get the SPFx webpart to load. The issue is with the spClientSidePageContext variable which contains the following properties: clientSideApplicationId, contextWebInfo, customActions, spPageContextInfo, manifests and perf.
We have found out that customActions and perf is not necessary for the webpart to load. The biggest issue here is the manifests property which contains multiple localized manifests for client side solutions and we want to create this property dynamically so we don't have to update it whenever we make a change to the webpart (and our solution is deployed to multiple farms with different localization so we can't hard code values for one language here).
We have worked out that it contains the manifest for classic-page-webpart-application and our web part among other solutions. If you go to a web part page with a SPFx webpart on it you can search the dom for "manifests" in order to find it.
By digging through Microsofts code in dotPeek we can see that the ClientSideWebPart class have private methods which gets these manifests and uses methods in the SPClientSideJavaScriptGenerator class to generate the inline script.
For some reason the ClientSideWebPart does not generate this when added to an application page.

Does anyone know how this can be achieved in the easiest way possible?

Comment: Which version of the SPFx framework is your web part using?

Comment: We are using version 1.4.1

Comment: Does the SPFx web part work on pages generated out-of-the-box, e.g. the classic home page?

Comment: Yes, it works on normal pages (out of the box, classic etc.). It's on custom application page, which resides in the hive, we are having problems, .

Comment: It wouldn't surprise me if the scenario you're describing isn't supported but I don't know. Someone on here might have an answer but you might be better off raising this as an issue on the SharePoint Framework GitHub: https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues

Comment: Yes, we have our suspicions about that :). Thanks for your input